# Display array of images in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I have image URL strings in a database. Then I retrieve the images and add them to `productimg_array`. I need to show the images in table view cells. I used SDWebImage for download images from URL. But only one image displaying all the Cell.

```
const char *sql = "SELECT id,cat_id,product_image,order_by,description FROM product";

NSLog(@"sql is %s",sql);

sqlite3_stmt *statement;

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
    // We "step" through the results - once for each row.
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        product_image = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
        NSLog(@"product_image is %@",product_image);

        [productimg_array addObject:product_image];

        NSLog(@"productimg_arr is %@",productimg_array);         
    }
}

sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

Table view:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{    
    NSLog(@"productimg_array is %lu",(unsigned long)[productimg_array count]);   
    return [productimg_array count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    for(int i=0; i<[productimg_array count];i++) {
        [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[productimg_array objectAtIndex:i]]
                       placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    }
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

Log output:

```
productimg_arr is (
    "http://server.net/projects/View/images/img.png",
    "http://server.net/projects/View/images/img1.png",
    "http://server.net/projects/View/images/img2.png",
    "http://server.net/projects/View/images/img3.png",
    "http://server.net/projects/View/images/img4.png",
    "http://server.net/projects/View/images/img5.png",
    "http://server.net/projects/View/images/img6.png"
)
```

Comment: As I understood from your code, you tried to load every image in 1 cell, Because your "for" block inside methor, which returns 1 cell. Replace your block to objectAtIndex:indexPath.row. I hope it will work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[productimg_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Then you will get different images in all cells.

Comment: Try to increase cell's height in method heightForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: You can also subclass UITableViewCell, to do customisation.

Answer (score 0):

Remove for loop from cellForRoeAtIndexPath and use indexPath.row instead of i.

Replace :

```
for(int i=0; i<[productimg_array count];i++){

    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[productimg_array objectAtIndex:i]]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
}
```

By :

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[productimg_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Comment: Hey, I'm using lazy loading SDWebImage. But the problem is only img image showing all the cells. [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[productimg_array objectAtIndex:i]]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];